# Add Web controllers to an Akka Actor System

Tags: java, spring-boot, akka

I am working with Akka and Spring.

I have an actor System that operates on a Kafka Stream set up (using `akka-stream-kafka_2.12`) and the actors hold some data in memory and persist their state using `akka-persistence`.

What I wanted to know is that can I create a REST-endpoint that can interact with my Actor-System to provide some data or send messages to my *actors*.

My question is, how can it be achieved?

Comment: Yes its possible, that is how our project works in which am currently working but the only difference is we are using PlayFramework instead of Spring. But it shouldn't be a problem. Hope https://www.baeldung.com/akka-with-spring this might be of some help.

Comment: @Unknown that's kinda a relief to hear that it's possible. The framework is not really a problem. I did stumble on that blog as well. It would be really helpful if you can share some code piece or a git demo project where you're calling an API and that API is interacting with your Akka Actor System to get data or current state of the Actors

Comment: Yeah sure, will create a demo spike project and share it to you. Where are you from? Just asking to know the time difference.

Comment: @Unknown That'll be of great help, I'd really appreciate that. I am currently in New Delhi India (so basically the same timezone).

Comment: Yeah, then no problem in timezone.

Comment: @Unknown looking forward to your sample

Comment: Posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, I have created a sample working application in github to demonstrate the usage of Spring with Akka.

**Please note that :**

1. I have used Springboot for quick setup and configuration.
2. You can't expect any kind of good/best practices in this demo
   project as i had to create this in 30 mins. It just explains one of
   the ways(simple) to use akka within Spring.
3. This sample cannot be used in microservice architure because there is
   no Remoting or Clustering involved here. API controllers directly talk to actors.
4. In Controllers, Used GetMapping in all places instead of PostMapping for simplicity.
5. Will update the repository with another sample explaining the usage
   with Clustering where the way of communication between API
   Controller and ActorSystem changes.

Here is the Link to [Repo](https://github.com/NeotericDev/PublicCodeSamples/tree/master/api-akka-integration). Hope this will get you started.

Either you can build the application yourself or run the api-akka-integration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar file in command prompt. It runs in default 8080 port.
This sample includes two kinds of APIs, `/Calc/{Operation}/{operand1}/{operand2}` and `/Chat/{message}`

/chat/hello

/calc/add/1/2

/calc/mul/1/2

/calc/div/1/2

/calc/sub/1/2

**Edit:2**

Updated the repo with Akka CLuster Usage in API

[API-Akka-Cluster](https://github.com/NeotericDev/PublicCodeSamples/tree/master/api-akka-cluster)

Comment: Cheers! I had a hunch on how it would work, works just the same. But most importantly you can't plug in Akka Streams with it can you?

Comment: Yeah, will try to push it along with the cluster implementation.

Comment: @iam.Carrot Added Cluster usage sample in the repo.

Comment: can you drop in your twitter handle? or any online handle where I can connect with you. Or you can directly drop a DM [on twitter here](https://twitter.com/iam_Carrot)

Comment: @iam.Carrot : I don't use Twitter. May be you can reach me on Gitter using my Github Id(https://gitter.im/NeotericDev)